# Which all reasons can cause index to go into unusable state in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

We are using oracle DB. In the "ALL_INDEXES" table for some of the indexes the status value is showing as "UNUSABLE". This we have observed when we move tables from compressed to uncompressed or vice versa. But we have not perform moving of the tables and still it showing for some of the indexes unusable. Can someone explain which all reasons are there.

Comment: Maybe tablespace full or not enough free space to handle indexes.

Comment: This question should not be closed. This has very often to do with programming. If the programmer write a procedure to purge old partitions, will "happen" an invalidation of indexes if he/she does not take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not creating lists on SO, but let's say the question is "What may caused the index go unusable?". The idea is that anything that touches the table(partition) segment with a "bulk" ddl operation, invalidates the index.

For example, if you truncate a partition or drop it, the global index will be set unusable.
(*Edit*: Here we can count also sqlldr-ing with direct path as discussed [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1859798300346695894))

Another reason would be that someone set it `unusable`;